# style.display is null - trying to loop over array and change display property

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, show-hide

Another newbie question from me.

Just checking whether my code below is possible. I.e creating a new array consisting of 'document.GetElementById's'. As i'm fairly new to javascript my code is generally a bit long winded, so please forgive the messiness.

The code below is bringing up the error 'style.display' is 'null' or not an object.
Can anyone see anything obvious i'm missing or doing wrong?

```
function Test(){

if(document.getElementById('inClient').value !=="FormViewer"){

    var visible =new Array("document.getElementById('personal2').value","document.getElementById('change_hours2').value");
    var change = new Array("document.getElementById('personal').value","document.getElementById('change_hours').value");

    for (var i=0; i <visible.length; i++) {
        if(visible[i]!==""){
            change[i].style.display = "block"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Basically if the hidden fields ('personal2' etc) are blank i want the div / section ('personal' etc) to remain hidden but if it contains text then i want to show the section.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do an `alert(change)` and have a look what the array contains. It does not contain DOM elements. Same for `visible`, it does not contain the values of the DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding strings to your array instead of references to DOM elements. Remove the quotes and the `value` property and it will work. You have to check the `value` within the iteration.

```
function Test(){

if(document.getElementById('inClient').value !=="FormViewer"){

    var visible =new Array(document.getElementById('personal2'), document.getElementById('change_hours2'));
    var change = new Array(document.getElementById('personal'), document.getElementById('change_hours'));

    for (var i=0; i <visible.length; i++) {
        if(visible[i].value != ""){
            change[i].style.display = "block"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, thats the sort of little thing i normally overlook. Will accept your answer in when it lets me.

Comment: @MarkWalters: One more thing, don't use `new Array`, use an array literal `var visible = [..., ...];`

Comment: @Felix Kling: not sure why i used new Array. But could you explain why i should use an array literal instead?

Comment: @Mark: The `Array` constructor is ambiguous. If you pass only one value, it will try to set the length  of the array to that value. If you pass two or more values, it will add those values to the array. This can easily lead to mistakes. The array literal is also shorter to write.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this, no double qoutes, it should work.

```
 var visible =new Array(document.getElementById('personal2').value,document.getElementById('change_hours2').value);
    var change = new Array(document.getElementById('personal').value,document.getElementById('change_hours').value);
```